# How to clone vm esxi without shutdown vm?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

How do we cloning the VM from VMWare ESXi without shutdown it? The VM is now on production so it will be impossible to shut it because it will create network impact.

Comment: Is your environment running free edition or is it licensed and running with vCenter Server?

Comment: @JeffHengesbach if it were the Free edition, would Converter still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vCenter Converter.

http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

You can specify the target as any virtual or physical machine. The converter is capable of making an exact copy without shutting down the target computer. This copy can then be placed back on the ESX server - or an a VMware workstation instance, as well as various other destinations.